# make-magit-popup-event: Symbol’s function definition is void: record [SOLVED]

Tags: magit

I get the above message using the latest magit from melpa.  This occurs with

GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2016-12-20

on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any ideas?

Comment: Records are a new feature in Emacs 26.1. Did you recently try out a newer Emacs version and while doing so update Magit/Magit-Popup? Uninstalling and reinstalling these packages with the Emacs version that you are actually using should fix the issue.

Comment: That's it!  I use a sync'd directory to keep my emacs config up to date on  half a dozen systems.  I guess I need to rethink that a bit.  Homebrew on macOS updated to emacs 26.  I need to find a PPA that has emacs-26 for my Ubuntu systems.

Comment: Instead of adding a `[SOLVED]` suffix, you should accept an answer. This is how questions are marked as solved here. You could also add your own answer and accept that, if you feel it is necessary to provide the additional information provided by your and my comments but that is not include in Stefan's answer.

Comment: @tarsius Thanks for the pointer.  I had seen [SOLVED] on another post so assumed that was the correct way.  Although I don't see a way to accept Stefan's answer??

Comment: On the right of his answer there are three circular buttons and a number. Click on the button at to buttom - the one that looks like a check mark.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed with tarsius: you probably have some package that was compiled with Emacs-26.  Make sure your packages are compiled with the older Emacs, since that's the direction for which we try to preserve compatibility.